# Regular Expression - Scala

Tags: regex, scala

I am new to Regular Expression and learning now. 
Could someone help to understand the below Regex?

```
val varPattern = new scala.util.matching.Regex("""(\$\{(\S+?)\})""", "fullVar", "value")
```

Thanks,
KaviJee

Answer (score 1):

```
(\$\{(\S+?)\})
```

I'll try to explain it by each symbol:

`(` is start of grouping

`\$` matches $ symbol, the backslash is because $ is a special character with another meaning

`\{` matches { symbol, the backslash is because { is a special character with another meaning

`(\S+?)` is a group that matches one or more of non whitespace characters

`\}` matches } symbol, the backslash is because } is a special character with another meaning

`)` is end of grouping

so the whole regex should match:

```
${ANYWORD}
```

Where ANYWORD is any characters that doesn't contain whitespaces.

Comment: I was too lazy to explain. " it matches quotation mark"? I don't understand that here.

Comment: The `"` characters are _not_ part of the regexp. Scala's triple quotes `"""` are used in place of a single quotes around the regexp string in order to avoid the need to escape the backslashes in `\$`, `\{` etc.

Comment: @mikej, I don't know Scala, I thought it's something like VB.NET, so the """ aren't included in the regex itself ?

Comment: Correct, none of the `"` are part of the regexp. In a regular string = `val pattern = `"\n"` the backslash is used for control characters such as newline, tab etc. If we want a literal backslash as part of a string we'd need to escape it e.g. `val pattern = `"\\$"`. As an alternative to doing that a bunch of times a triple-quoted string (where backslashes are treated literally) can be used.

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I am confused about (\S+?) and (\S+). Because (\S+) and (\S+?) gives the same result. Then, what is the meaning of ?

Comment: "greediness", I added an example but I'll let Youssef explain it. It may not matter for the example.

Comment: `X+?` is 'one or more times', with a reluctant qualifier. See the docs for it here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html

Answer (score 1):

```
scala> "${abc}" match { case varPattern(full, value) => s"$full / $value" }
res0: String = ${abc} / abc
```

Unless you are using group names with the standard library regex, it's more usual to see:

```
scala> val r = """(\$\{(\S+?)\})""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\$\{(\S+?)\})
```

Edit, they also allow:

```
scala> val r = """(\$\{(\S+?)\})""".r("full", "val")
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\$\{(\S+?)\})
```

Greedy example:

```
scala> val r = """(\S+?)(a*)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\S+?)(a*)

scala> "xyzaa" match { case r(prefix, suffix) => s"$prefix, $suffix" }
res11: String = xyz, aa

scala> val r = """(\S+)(a*)""".r
r: scala.util.matching.Regex = (\S+)(a*)

scala> "xyzaa" match { case r(prefix, suffix) => s"$prefix, $suffix" }
res12: String = "xyzaa, "
```

Comment: Thank you all for your reply. I am confused about (\S+?) and (\S+). Because (\S+) and (\S+?) gives the same result. Then, what is the meaning of ?